# playing a WAV file on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, html, safari, mobile-safari

I'm struggling to get a WAV file to play on a HTML page as either an HTML5 audio tag or via a regular downloadable link in mobile Safari (iPad/iPhone):

```
<audio controls src="audio-pcm_s16le-8k.wav"/></audio>
<a href="audio-pcm_s16le-8k.wav">audio</a>
```

The HTML5 `audio` object just shows `Cannot play audio file` in it, and when I click to download the anchor referenced one I get a black page with a "can't play this circle" in the middle.  I've tried various frequencies (8000, 11025, 16000, 32000, 44100), various encodings (mu-law, Linear Signed 16-bit LE and BE), various containers (.wav, .caf, .aiff), and various audio conversion programs (Audacity, ffmpeg, and Apple's own afconvert)... I can't get audio to play (unless I make it MP3 -- and no, I can't just use MP3 or AAC, I need a "raw" format for reasons too long to get in to here).

I looked at the supported formats for iOS and it appears to support WAV... anyone got any experience with this issue?  I'm on latest iOS 6.0.1

**EDIT:** The selected answerer got me to the issue, but the reason is in the comments of the answer.  Bottom line is it requires HTML range headers for playing the files.

Comment: can you provide an example audio file that is not working?

Comment: @madmik3 sure i put one of the test files here: [link](http://wikisend.com/download/687328/conference-pcm_s16le-8k.wav)

Comment: Multiple applications tell me this wav file is not a valid wav file. The file itself is invalid for some reason or another. I would find a wav from another source and verify it plays in quicktime.

Comment: Thanks for checking... that's odd though, on my Windows box, Windows Media Player plays it fine, Audacity plays it fine, Ffmpeg reads it fine... what apps are telling you it's not fine?  Here's the .caf file I did using a Mac I have (which also didn't work): [link](http://wikisend.com/download/448684/conference8k.caf)

Comment: Well, you've certainly gotten me on the right track at least... it's apparently not the file at all... it's the web server.  Same exact content from stockley works, but on my web server it doesn't.  I'll have to look over the HTTP response in detail I suppose.  My web server is returning `Content-Type: audio/x-wav` so it's not that...

Comment: I've not changed anything on the server, mine is a default configuration (not a web admin, so not sure what they are!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Well, you've certainly gotten me on the right track at least... it's apparently not the file at all... it's the web server. Same exact content from stockley works, but on my web server it doesn't. I'll have to look over the HTTP response in detail I suppose. My web server is returning `Content-Type: audio/x-wav` so it's not that...

Checking the headers for the test site I set up, you want to be returning `Content-Type: text/html` for the page containing the HTML data you need:

[image]

And `Content-Type: audio/x-wav` for the actual audio file (`http://www.test.com/file.wav`)

[image]

Comment: I have a hunch it's the `Range:` header... my guess is Safari is requiring it's use (whereas desktop Chrome, FF, etc. don't).  I'll post back when I know more...

Comment: It was the `Range:` header... once I enabled that all was good in the universe again.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: how do you get HTTP request status , I mean which tool do you use

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/hplfkkmefamockhligfdcfgfnbcdddbg?hl=en

Comment: @mark, how can I enable the `Range:` header? My wav file is on my server, and I have an html5 audio element very similar to that in the original question.

Comment: @BillCheatham This really does depend on your server provider and their setup. Byte-range support is enabled by default in Apache I believe, but may differ for your setup. Search for how to enable byte-range support.

Answer (score 9):

Through a run of trial and error I found that you need a content-range header for it to work. Here's an example of my headers that allows a wav file to play in Safari for iOS:

```
Content-Range: bytes XX-XX/XX
Content-Type: audio/wav 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="whatever.WAV" 
Content-Length: XX
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It works great. I used **Content-Range: bytes XX-XX/XX** and **Content-Length: XX**

Comment: What is XX? Like this? `'Content-Range' => 'bytes 0-' . $fileSize . '/' . $fileSize`