# Cannot play wav file on safari

Tags: html, ios, ruby-on-rails, safari, wav

I'm trying to play a wav file on safari. Pretty much the same question as this: [playing a WAV file on iOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275409/playing-a-wav-file-on-ios-safari)

But the accepted answers aren't working. I'm using a rails server with apache and phusion passenger. The audio file plays fine on chrome but not on any safari (desktop, mobile, and through uiwebview).

I'm sending the file in rails with

```
send_file filename, :type => "audio/x-wav", :disposition => "inline"
```

From the other stack overflow q&a, I tried adding Content-Range and Content-Length headers to the response

```
size = File.size(filename)
response.header["Content-Range"] = "bytes 0-#{size-1}/#{size}"
response.header["Content-Length"] = "#{size}"
```

The error i'm receiving is pretty nondescript "Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load"

Here are the headers of the response

```
x-runtime   0.589797
Date    Wed, 17 Aug 2016 16:38:49 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
Server  Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By    Phusion Passenger 5.0.7
Status  200 OK
Content-Type    audio/x-wav
content-range   bytes 0-3243/3244
Cache-Control   private
Content-Transfer-Encoding   binary
Content-Disposition inline; filename="eng-182-msg0026.wav"
Connection  close
Content-Length  3244
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
x-runtime   0.589797
```

Answer (score 1):

When requesting a direct link to a media file this would work. But I was requesting this through a controller. Safari was making multiple http requests each for a certain range. The server was responding with the entire file every time which is why it fails.

The annoying thing is that the Safari web inspector decides not to show the "Range" header in the network request. It'll show other http headers but not the most important one in this case...

Anyways, short answer, respond back with the the correct byte range that each request wants.

Comment: can you show how did you fix that problem. I'm having it too.

Comment: @ tamy and @levi What did you do to get audio to work in Safari? I'm having this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, playing audio files on the Safari didn't work, but on the Chrome and every other browser everything worked as expected.

Set proper Content-Range in response header solve my problem. I used forked gem [send_file_with_range](https://github.com/metalels/send_file_with_range/tree/rails51), which contain fix for the Rails 5.1.

I recommend this gem because code in this gem is pretty simple and short, and this solution seems like the simplest and quickest.

**Note**: this solution is specific for the Ruby on Rails developers, but general solution is to set proper Content-Range in the response header, for every request.

I hope that this will be helpful for somebody.